# Why canReveal() of GateKeeper was called before the EventHandler was called (GWT)?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I got a Header presenter which is the nested presenter. The Customer presenter is the child of Header presenter (ie the Customer presenter was put into a slot of Header presenter).

So I want to use MyGateKeeper to manage login page. The HeaderPresenter that will fire PassUserInfoEvent.

```
public class MyGateKeeper implements Gatekeeper{
private String loginedUserID="";

private final EventBus eventBus;

@Inject
public MyGateKeeper (final EventBus eventBus){

    this.eventBus = eventBus;


    this.eventBus.addHandler(PassUserInfoEvent.getType(), new PassUserInfoHandler(){

        @Override
        public void onPassUserInfo(PassUserInfoEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String userID=event.getUserID();
            loginedUserID=userID;   
        }

    });
}

@Override
public boolean canReveal(){
    System.out.println(loginedUserID+"Test");
    if(!loginedUserID.equals("")){
        System.out.println(loginedUserMeaningID+"cxcxc");
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

In the CustomerPresenter:

```
@ProxyCodeSplit
@NameToken(NameTokens.cust)
@UseGatekeeper(MyGateKeeper.class)
public interface MyProxy extends ProxyPlace<CustomerPresenter> {
}
```

However after run, it does not show the Gui even I loggined. I tested & found that `canReveal()` in MyGateKeeper was called before `PassUserInfoHandler()` was called, so `canReveal` never `return true`;

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The usual pattern to accomplish this is to bind a `CurrentUser` class in `Singleton`:

```
bind(CurrentUser.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

and inject it into your `GateKeeper`. Inside your `GateKeeper`'s `canReveal` method, you'll check that `currentUser.isLoggedIn()` :

```
private final CurrentUser currentUser;

@Inject
MyGateKeeper(CurrentUser currentUser) {
    this.currentUser = currentUser;
} 

@Override
public boolean canReveal() {
    return currentUser.isLoggedIn();
}
```

You should initialize the `CurrentUser.isLoggedIn` field inside your `Bootstrapper` (see https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Bootstrapping-or-Application-Initialization) by calling your server. Here's an example using GWTP's `RestDispatch`:

```
public class BootstrapperImpl implements Bootstrapper {
    private final String unauthorizedPlace;
    private final CurrentUser currentUser;
    private final PlaceManager placeManager;
    private final RestDispatch restDispatch;
    private final UserResource userResource;

    @Inject
    BootstrapperImpl(
            @UnauthorizedPlace String unauthorizedPlace,
            CurrentUser currentUser,
            PlaceManager placeManager,
            RestDispatch restDispatch,
            UserResource userResource) {
        this.unauthorizedPlace = unauthorizedPlace;
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
        this.placeManager = placeManager;
        this.restDispatch = restDispatch;
        this.userResource = userResource;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBootstrap() {
        checkIfUserIsLoggedIn();
    }

    private void checkIfUserIsLoggedIn() {
        restDispatch.execute(userResource.isCurrentUserLoggedIn(), new AbstractAsyncCallback<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Boolean isCurrentUserLoggedIn) {
                navigate(isCurrentUserLoggedIn);
            }
        });
    }

    private void navigate(Boolean isCurrentUserLoggedIn) {
        currentUser.setLoggedIn(isCurrentUserLoggedIn);

        if (isCurrentUserLoggedIn) {
            placeManager.revealCurrentPlace();
        } else {
            placeManager.revealPlace(new PlaceRequest.Builder().nameToken(unauthorizedPlace).build());
        }
    }
}
```